# Jax ws и jax rs это servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs, jax-ws

Вот Spring MVC это простые сервлеты. Является ли реализации jax ws и jax rs основанными на servletax? к примеру те же Jersey и Metro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jax-Rs и Jax-Ws это JEE спецификации , а Jersey и Metro их реализации. Не знаю что под капотом у Jersey, но на 100% уверен, что он использует сервлеты, так же как и Spring MVC (dispatcher).

Comment: почему бы тогда сразу просто не использовать сервлеты?

Comment: Одна из главных причин - сложность кода. Представьте , что у вас есть страница. На странице существует 10+  ссылок. Если сделать маппинг при помощи сервлетов , то вам понадобится 10 классов. А используя Jax rs вам понадобится всего лишь 1 класс  , в котором будет 10 маппингов. Удобно , не правда ли ?

Comment: Да, на много удобнее, тогда зачем нужен сервлет, это очень не удобно получается

Comment: не только ведь для того чтобы реализовать jax rs, jax ws

Comment: @JNat для абстракции сетевого взаимодействия. Вам стоит поближе познакомится с ООП, а то сейчас ваши вопросы выглядят как "Зачем мне под столом системный блок, если всё показывает монитор?"

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev я отвечал чуть выше, не только ведь для абстракции, нужен сервлет. Вопрос для чего он нужен разработчикам, не разрабатывающие фреймворки, если есть другая же спецификация удобнее, хотелось бы знать где можно применять кроме фреймворков,